# Creating HTTP site on llinux

Tags: linux, apache, http

I want to create **HTTP** site on linux to access files & folders. I tried creating the site, but i could access only .html file content from /var/www path. My requirement is to create a site to access files like xml, txt & also some folders in it from different location.

Please guide me with the steps & places/files where i need to make a changes.

TIA

Comment: I did some troubleshoot and found the problem. It was basically problem with user i had enter in httpd.confd file. After providing user as root & modifying the root directory, i got it working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably have to change the permissions of the document. Try the chmod command to change the permissions to be accessible to the web.

```
chmod 775 <filename>
```

See https://serverfault.com/questions/357108/what-permissions-should-my-website-files-folders-have-on-a-linux-webserver for more details

Comment: Thanks for your feedback......I did some troubleshoot and found the problem. It was  basically problem with user i had enter in httpd.confd file. After providing user as root & modifying the root directory, i got it working.